# On eclipse, how to get editor tabs sorted by most recently used?

Tags: eclipse

I like to work with a lot of tabs open, but I can't see any logic to which tabs stay visible on the screen versus which tabs get hidden and stored in the column down the right hand side.

I would like it to keep my tabs ordered so that the left most tab is the file I have edited most recently, the one next to that the next most recent and so on.

I've spent 30 minutes looking through options and googling and can't find anything. Can someone help? Where can I set editor tab ordering strategies?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the **preferences *General > Appearance***, there is an option ***Show most recently used tabs*** that you would want to enable for that.

See also [Eclipse Project 4.5 M6 - New and Noteworthy - "Visible tabs shown on overflow" behavior decoupled from appearance theme](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.5/M6/#mru-tabs)

Comment: Thanks. Unless I am mistaken, that is an option entitled 'Visible tabs on overflow' and refers to the ordering of the tabs down the right hand side for the tabs that are not displayed. I want a strategy for ordering the tabs that are displayed, not the ones that are hidden.

Comment: This also affects the order of the visible tabs when an editor is opened for which there is not enough space for its tab. But the order will be most recently opened, not most recently edited. I don't think there is an option for most recently edited tab order without an additional plugin which I don't know if it exists or has to be written (but I know there is an API for it). To navigate to the previous edit location(s) use Ctrl+Alt+Left.